# I can not get the Angular 2 quick-start tutorial to run

Tags: angularjs, windows, angular, http-status-code-404

I am brand new to Angular and decided to start with the quickstart tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html I have completed all the steps and also been back and double checked all my files are exactly as shown in the tutorial, but I can not get it to work and have no idea where to start to fix the problem.

I am running on Windows 10. I downloaded and installed the latest stable build of Node (v4.4.7) and NPM (2.15.8). They seem to run just fine. After I type `npm start` my `ts` files get transpiled into `js` files and the browser opens, but the browser displays "Cannot GET /" instead of displaying the quickstart app, and Fiddler shows me that the server returned a 404 error.

The address bar in my browser contains `http://localhost:3000/`

In my command window the server outputs a line of text each time I refresh my browser, so they are talking to each other. This is an example of one of the lines output to the console window `[1] 16.07.04 15:43:09 404 GET /index.html`.

Where do I start to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your link it says:

```
Verify that you are running at least node v5.x.x and npm 3.x.x by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older versions produce errors.
```

I'm running node 6.2.1 and I was able to reproduce everything in the tutorial a few weeks back when I started with Angular 2.

The latest seems to be 6.2.2. See here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Comment: Thanks. The tutorial suggests installing node from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ which is the latest stable release. This somewhat contradicts the instruction to verify that you are running at least node v5.x.x which is at a different URL. It is working for me now so I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the lines of interest

```
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 16.08.20 17:57:32 404 GET /index.html
```

I had this same issue and realized that I had created `index.html` in `app/` instead of the root directory one level below. Once the file was moved everything worked.